# Dynamic video element - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I'm trying to establish some familiarity with dynamic elements in JavaScript. I have put together a very basic example, which will autoplay a small video (stretched to fill the screen as per attached CSS file).

The CSS file:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50%; bottom:-50%;
    left:-50%; right:-50%;
    margin:auto;
}
video {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50%; bottom:-50%;
    left:-50%; right:-50%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

An my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
    <video autoplay id="VideoPlayer" src=Video.mp4></video>
</head>
</html>
```

This works as planned. When the page is opened, 'Video.mp4' is stretched to fit the browser window and play automatically. This same process works if I replace the video element with an image element; the image is stretched to fit the window and displayed on the page being opened.

However, I want to be able to create both image and video elements dynamically. I.e. user input can change the element from a video (stretched to fit the browser window) and an image (stretched to fit the browser window). My attempt to create and display either a video or image through this process results in a blank (white) screen.

My attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript'>
    var DynamicVideo = document.createElement("video");
    DynamicVideo.autoplay = true;
    DynamicVideo.src = 'Video.mp4';
    document.head.appendChild(DynamicVideo);
</script>
</body>
```

I've inspected the page within Chrome, and the video element has been appended to the head as required. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you putting your content in your head tag?

Comment: I just changed it to <body> and it now works perfectly. It's just one of those days I guess. Thanks @Nit!